# Python multithreading but using object instance

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop

I hope you can help me.

I have a `msgList`, containing `msg` objects, each one having the `pos` and `content` attributes.
Then I have a function `posClassify`, that creates a `SentimentClassifier` object, that iterates thru this `msgList` and does `msgList[i].pos = clf.predict(msgList[i].content)`, being `clf` an instance of `SentimentClassifier`.

```
def posClassify(msgList):
    clf = SentimentClassifier()
    for i in tqdm(range(len(msgList))):
        if msgList[i].content.find("omitted") == -1:
            msgList[i].pos = clf.predict(msgList[i].content)
```

And what I wanted is to compute this using multiprocessing. I have read that you create a pool, and call a function with a list of the arguments you want to pass this function, and thats it. I imagine that that function must be something like saving an image or working on different memory spaces, and not like mine, where you want to modify that same `msg` object, and also, having to use that `SentimentClassifier` object (which takes about 10 seconds or so to initialize).

My thoughts where creating cpu_cores-1 processes, each one using an instance of `SentimentClassifier`, and then each process starts consuming that msg list with its own classifier, but I can't work out how to approach this. I also thought of creating threads with binary semaphores, each one calling its own classifier, and then waiting the semaphore to update the `pos` value in the `msg` object, but still cant figure it out.

Comment: Have you actually tried what you think you should be doing? What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ProcessPoolExecutor` from `futures` module in Python.

### The `ProcessPoolExecutor` is

> An Executor subclass that executes calls asynchronously using a pool
> of at most max_workers processes. If max_workers is None or not given,
> it will default to the number of processors on the machine

You can find more at [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor).

Here, is the sample code of achieving the concurrency assuming that each `msgList[i]` is independent of `msgList[j]` when `i != j`,

```
from concurrent import futures

def posClassify(msg, idx, clf):
    return idx, clf.predict(msg.content)

def classify(msgList):
    clf = SentimentClassifier()

    calls = []

    executor = futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
    for i in tqdm(range(len(msgList))):
        if msgList[i].content.find("omitted") == -1:
            call = executor.submit(posClassify, msgList[i], i, clf)
            calls.append(call)

    # wait for all processes to finish
    executor.shutdown()

    # assign the result of individual calls to msgList[i].pos
    for call in calls:
        result = call.result()
        msgList[result[0]].pos = result[1]
```

*In order to execute the code, just call the `classify(msgList)` function.*

Comment: Since ``msg`` in the subprocess is likely a copy (unless explicitly made multiprocess aware), the results don't affect the original ``msgList`` in the main process. It will discard all results.

Comment: The following error is thrown: `TypeError: posClassify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'idx'`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but, the problem comes with `clf = SentimentClassifier`, that takes around 10 seconds each time its instanced. The solution would be creating 4 (n of processes) of this clf, and then each process work with its own instance of the classifier, but I cant manage how to reach this solution, as I dont know how to work correctly with processes and those instances.

Comment: Well  in that case you could just create one instance of classifier and pass it to the `posClassify` method. What do you think?

Comment: What's the average running time of `clf.predict` method?

Comment: Okay, I'll try. The avg time is around 7.5 iterations per second of the original for loop.